# Testing webauthn in the ios simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, webauthn

Does anyone know if testing webauthn in the iOS simulator (xcode 12) with ios 14.4 is possible? I tried it with https://webauthn.io and using an iPhone 8 with fingerprint enabled and iPhone 11 with faceid enabled but in both cases it does not seem work.

Comment: Hi, by any chance did u find a way to test the webauthn api in the simulator

Comment: no unfortunately not yet

Answer (score -2):

**How to launch iOS simulator with Safari developer tools**

1.Install XCode. If you are developing on Mac, chances are you already installed XCode. You can either use the Apple App Store (easiest way) to install XCode or get the DMG/XIP file to install it if you do not use the App Store.

2.Start iPhone/iOS Simulator.app to launch the Simulator. If you have not created a simulator yet, you need to do this in XCode. You can have multiple simulators as you might want to test on different devices. I recommend creating a shortcut so you do not need to open XCode every time you want to launch a simulator.

3.Open the Safari browser in the Simulator. As mentioned above, other browsers like Chrome are not supported.

4.Open the Safari browser on your Mac device to connect it with the Safari browser in the simulator. Now you should be able to use the Safari developer tools like in any other web page: see the DOM, set breakpoints for debugging, perform network analysis and much more.

Comment: this is a generic answer for the iOS simulator and devtools. I'm looking for the webauthn part....